# Google Analytics URL parameters

Tags: php, analytics, tracking, qr-code

I need to make a single page (videos.php) to download a .MP4 video file based on an URL parameter.
That page is to be used in conjunction with a QR code in a printed magazine.

i.e

```
?file=videofiles/video1.mp4
```

or

```
?file=videofiles/video2.mp4
```

What I am unsure of is if Google Analytics will track that page with separate parameters or just as a single page where a hit on both videos will count as hit on videos.php without regard to the video itself.

I want to be able to view the hits on both videos separately. 
Will Analytics take care of the parameter or is there a better / other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Google's Custom Campaign Tracking Tool

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033863
and
http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1033867&topic=1032998&ctx=topic

Answer (score 2):

I did it a long time ago. I paste here for you my config (I don't know if something has changed and I don't know if it's the best solution... but can be a point of start):

In your analytics page:

- click on Admin (top right),
- click on `Filters` tab
- `new filter`
- Choose `Advanced`
- Create new filter (choose name and domain)
- `Custom filter`
- `Advanced`

  Field A -> Extract A Referral `(.*)`

  Field B -> Extract B -

  Output To -> Constructor `User-defined` `$A1`

Field A Required Yes

Field B Required No

Override Output Field Yes

Case-sensitive No

Answer (score 0):

You can configure url destination goals for the same url with different parameters. Look here: http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1116091